# AJAX Load more on CPT returning random posts

Tags: ajax, javascript

i have pieced together a post grid loop with AJAX Load More button for posts from a CPT category but I cant get the offset to work properly. There are supposed to be 6 posts per page but at the moment it loads the next 6 posts in random order and duplicates some of them. Also I need the button to disappear when there are no more posts to load, i cant find how to do this anywhere!

Template code:

```
<?php 
    $postsPerPage = 6;
    $args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'ce_project',
        'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
        'offset' => $offset,
        'category_name' => 'branding',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    ); ?>
          <div class="tabgrid">
          

  <?php  $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-postgrid' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

           </div>
           <div class="loadmore-row"><a id="more_posts"></a></div>
```

Functions.php:

```
function more_post_ajax(){
    $offset = $_POST["offset"];
    $ppp = $_POST["ppp"];
    header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'ce_project',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'offset' => $offset,
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) { $loop->the_post(); 
      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-postgrid' );
    }

    exit; 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     
    var ajaxUrl = "http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
    var page = 1; // What page we are on.
    var ppp = 6; // Post per page

    $("#more_posts").on("click",function(){ // When btn is pressed.
        $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
        $.post(ajaxUrl, {
            action:"more_post_ajax",
            offset: (page * ppp) + 1,
            ppp: ppp
        }).success(function(posts){
            page++;
            $(".tabgrid").append(posts); // CHANGE THIS!
            $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",false);
        });

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code it will work as I have used this and working fine at my end.

```
<?php

$querystr = "
    SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
    WHERE $wpdb->terms.slug = 'branding'
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'taxonomy_name'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'ce_project'
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC";
    
    $result1 = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
    $totalPosts = count($result1);

$querystr2 = "
    SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
    WHERE $wpdb->terms.slug = 'branding'
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'taxonomy_name'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'ce_project'
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0,6";
    
    $result2 = $wpdb->get_results($querystr2);
    
    foreach($result2 as $post){
        
        echo '<h2 class="search-item__title">'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</h2>';
        
    }
?>

<input type="hidden" id="row" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" id="all" value="<?php echo $totalPosts; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="taxonomy" value="taxonomy_name" />
<input type="hidden" id="term_id" value="branding" />

<div class="loader" style="display:none;"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/loader-fading.gif" alt="loading.." /></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 //alert('dfd');
 $(window).scroll(function(){
 
  var position = $(window).scrollTop() + 1;
  var bottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
  
    console.log('Position: '+position);
  console.log('Bottom: '+bottom);
  
  if( position > bottom ){
   var row = Number($('#row').val());
   var allcount = Number($('#all').val());
   var taxonomy = $('#taxonomy').val();
   var term_id = $('#term_id').val();   
   var rowperpage = 10;
   row = row + rowperpage;

   if(row <= allcount){
        $('#row').val(row);
        jQuery(".loader").css('display','block');
        row = "row=" + row + "&cat_name=" + taxonomy + "&cat_id=" + term_id + "&action=get_archive";
        $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
         data: row,
         success: function(response){
            //console.log(response);
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $(".search-item:last").after(response).show().fadeIn("slow");
                $(".loader").css('display','none');
            }, 1000);
            
         }
        });
   }
  }

 });
 
});
</script>

<?php
// copye and paste the below function in functions.php file.
// AJAX request for auto load listing
function get_archive(){
    global $wpdb;
    
    $html = '';
    $row = $_POST['row'];
    $cat_name = $_POST['cat_name'];
    $cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];
    $rowperpage = 6;

    $querystr2 = "
    SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
    WHERE $wpdb->terms.slug = '".$cat_id."'
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = '".$cat_name."'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'ce_project'
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC LIMIT ".$row.",".$rowperpage."";
    
    $result2 = $wpdb->get_results($querystr2);

    // Check form ajax action 
    if($_POST['action'] == 'get_archive')
    {
        
        foreach($result2 as $post){

            $html .= '<h2 class="search-item__title">'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</h2>';
                
        }       

        echo $html;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }

exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_archive', 'get_archive' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_archive', 'get_archive' );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried to implement this but it displays nothing. I don't think it is the solution for me. it should loop "get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-postgrid' );" also i dont see here where the 'load more' button is placed?? sorry!

Comment: You can customize the loop or post types/taxonomy as per your need. Regarding, the load more button you can add a button and call the ajax onClick of button. My code is for auto scroll loading results and its working fine at my end..